# mapping multiple context roots to single application

Tags: java

I was searching for a solution since 2 days on How can we map multiple contexts Roots to single deployed application?
Lets give more details...
We have one application(lets call it as All) which should deploy once and refer with multiple context roots so that each customer can access this application with different url's.

```
ex: http://localhost:8080/Customer1 ===> webapp(All) 
    http://localhost:8080/Customer2 ===> webapp(All)
```

I have tried using Apache's `ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse` options as shown below.
But when server receives requests from clients it can see context path of application that gets deployed on server in this case ALL(not as CustomerX). At server side i need to know which customer(context root) requested so that i can load customer specific login page,data etc..

```
  ProxyPass /Customer1 http://localhost:8083/ALL
  ProxyPassReverse /Customer1 http://localhost:8083/ALL
  ProxyPass /Customer2 http://localhost:8083/ALL
  ProxyPassReverse /Customer2 http://localhost:8083/ALL
```

Then later on i got to know about weblogic's Sahred library concept and it worked..!
In weblogic we can deploy application as shared library and refer it with different context roots from different web applications(dummy).
So in my case i need to create dummy web applications(for Customer 1,Customer2...Customer n ) and refer shared library application from these applications.
If we take shared library approach,what are pros and cons? What about memory consumption,session management?
Any suggestions?Are there any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

These web applications will not be really dummy. For every application the server should create a specific Classloader and everything else. So, using this approach you will use consume more memory, even with a shared library. Actually, you could also isolate shared libraries to avoid one client "disturb" another. Ideally, all clients should be totally isolated because one client should not pay for another client troubles (ex: excessive resources usage).

- Same webapp:
  Isolation per request
  Shared resources: Computational Resources, Operating System, Application Server resources, Classes, Objects Pool, etc
  Note: only one version
- Different webapps using isolated shared lib
  Isolation per classloader
  Shared resources: Computational Resources, Operating System, Application Server resources, Classes code from shared lib
  (Deployment/Releases synchronized)
  Note: only one version
- Different webapps no shared libs
  Isolation per classloader
  Shared resources: Computational Resources, Operating System and Application Server resources
  (some kind of isolation in deployment)
  Overhead: web application footprint
- Different app servers
  Isolation per (Java) Virtual Machine
  Shared resources: Computational Resources (could be somehow isolated) and Operating System
  Overhead: application server footprint + web application footprint
- Different virtual machines:
  Isolation per (OS) Virtual Machine
  Shared resources: Computational Resources (could be isolated)
  Overhead: OS footprint (somehow minimized by smart virtualizations) + web application footprint

*Computational Resources: Disk space, I/O, CPU and Memory*

Comment: Thanks for reply..Actually we need this solution for ASP model deployment where all customers(client's) share common resources and pay's for it.I agree with you that server loads each and every  application with its own class loader.But in this context..what happens when server receives request will it directly pass that request to shared app? or to intermediate app(dummy in this case) then to shared app?